# Terraform no matching SecurityGroup found

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to configure my terraform for Dev and QA environments, each of which have their own Security Groups, which I specify with the `data` tag:

```
data "aws_security_group" "ssh" {
  name = "SG-SSH"
}

data "aws_security_group" "postgres" {
  name = "SG-Postgres"
}
```

Is there a way to specify which security groups get pulled in based on which environment is being targeted? I tried this:

```
locals {
  sgs = {
    dev  = ["${data.aws_security_group.postgres.id}", "${data.aws_security_group.ssh.id}"]
    qa   = ["${data.aws_security_group.postgres.id}"]
  }
}
```

Which I then reference with `"${local.sgs[var.env]}"`. However, the `ssh` security group only exists in the Dev environment so when I target the QA environment, I still get:

```
data.aws_security_group.ssh: data.aws_security_group.ssh: no matching SecurityGroup found
```

Comment: Creating an ssh SG in the QA environment isn't allowed :(

Answer (score 0):

As per the Terraform [Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html), you can specify conditional operations as follows:

> CONDITION ? TRUEVAL : FALSEVAL

Then for example, you can define your security groups as follows:

```
locals {
  sgs = "${var.env == "dev" ? ["${data.aws_security_group.postgres.id}", "${data.aws_security_group.ssh.id}"] : ["${data.aws_security_group.postgres.id}"]}"
}
```

And call it with `"${local.sgs}"` - which will get all security groups based on the environment specified in `var.env`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea that moebius suggested is in right direction , but slightly wrong in the syntax, which is (according to  [Terraform Conditional Documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.1.x/configuration-0-11/interpolation)

> > CONDITION ? TRUEVAL : FALSEVAL

So there should be only value passed both in when the condition is right or wrong.

So instead of

```
locals {
  sgs = "${var.env == "dev" ? ["${data.aws_security_group.postgres.id}", "${data.aws_security_group.ssh.id}"] : ["${data.aws_security_group.postgres.id}"]}"
}
```

Try using

```
locals {
  sgs = "${var.env == "dev" ? ["${data.aws_security_group.ssh.id}"] : ["${data.aws_security_group.postgres.id}"]}"
}
```